# Restoring a System State Backup

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, restore, system-state

We had a server die the other day, and while it is up and running again now, I don't anticipate it will continue to be for long- So I've started building a temporary server as a replacement. I have a System State image backed up from the existing server, and would like to place it onto the new one. This system state image is in the form of a .VHDX volume. How do I restore this system state to the temporary server?

Using the System Recovery Options on a windows install disk has proven to be a dead end. If the .VHDX and image files are on a local storage device, the image does not get listed in the recovery options dialog. I do not have an option to manually select the image i'd like to recover. If I put the image files on a Network Share and select to search here for a system state image, the image is still not listed in the recovery options dialog. I have found no way to get the Windows-provided recovery software to actually recognize that there is valid recovery data available.

Are there alternative software available that will allow me to deploy this image, can this be forced through a command line, etc. or should I just give up and start looking at alternate recovery options?

Comment: You tagged this question "domain controller". Is the backup image of a domain controller?

Comment: Yes, the server is a domain controller. I know I am likely to encounter issues with this procedure given this detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a domain controller. Do not restore a system state backup unless the system the backup was taken from is dead and offline and will not be recovered. THERE CAN BE ONLY ONE.

Just install Windows from scratch and promote it to a domain controller. You're not going to save that much time over trying to do a restore.